# How to fit a GLM to a dataset estimating "only the post hoc values for the random effects"?

Tags: r, cross-validation, lme4, mixed-models

My goal is to implement a cross-validation procedure for linear mixed models. Let me start with what I want to do ([which is described here](http://www.scopus.com/record/display.url?eid=2-s2.0-84880703535&origin=inward&txGid=80F6981702312FFFA5C3D23C710C379E.kqQeWtawXauCyC8ghhRGJg%3A2)), and already tell you that I get stuck at step 4. The goal:

1. Fit a GLM to the data with one subject removed (leave-one-out crossvalidation)
2. Fix the model's parameter values to the estimates of this fitted model
3. Fit the same model again to all data (now including the removed subject), without any major iterations **estimating only the post hoc values of the random effects**
4. Calculate predicted values for the previously-left-out subject i Use the post hoc estimate of the random effects for this subject
5. *... the rest is not important for my question ...*

I am struggling with point number 4. Spedfically (1) what exactly it means to estimate only the post hoc values of the random effects and (2) how I would implement that using the ´lmer´ command.

Here is an example with where I get stuck

```
# Lets assume we wanna do this in the inbuilt dataset sleepstudy
library(lme4)
# First, we quickly look at the data structure
str(sleepstudy)
 # 'data.frame':   180 obs. of  3 variables:
 # $ Reaction: num  250 259 251 321 357 ...
 # $ Days    : num  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 # $ Subject : Factor w/ 18 levels "308","309","310",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

# Then we do the cross-validation (to illustrate, for one subject only)
# Leave the following subject out
i   <- "308"
# 1.)2.)3.) Fit a model to all but this subject, fix the effects by storing it in fm1
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), data = sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject!=i,])
# 4.) Now I should estimate for all data but with zero iterations. How?

# 5.) Then I can hopefully predict values for the previously-left-out subject i
pr1 <- predict(fm1, sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject==i], allow.new.levels=T) #we need to allow new levels as i is not in the levels of the random effects which we fitted
```

Anyone having an idea or done something similar?
Thanks a lot!

JBJ